# Remove sticky behavior from top navigation on twenty fourteen theme?

Tags: css, headers, theme-twenty-fourteen

In wordpress theme twentyfourteen, I am wondering how to remove the sticky behavior of the top navigation with a 100% width header background image like [this site](http://braidingfreedom.com)?

I would love to have a top image with full width and a max-height with the navigation just placed under it, but the navigation sticks to the top of the window in the browser when you scroll down.

I ended up using the following .js with twentythirteen child theme

```
//$(document).ready(function() {
jQuery().ready(function($) {
var stickyNavTop = $('.navbar').offset().top;

var stickyNav = function(){
var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();

if (scrollTop > stickyNavTop) { 
$('.navbar').addClass('sticky');
} else {
$('.navbar').removeClass('sticky'); 
}
};

stickyNav();

$(window).scroll(function() {
stickyNav();
});
});
```

and added

```
 .sticky { position: fixed; z-index: 100; ... }
```

Thanks to a post found in here.

I could have apply the same to the twentyfourteen, but it was tricky and I had no time to waste.

Comment: This is a question better asked using the CSS tag at Stackoverflow. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css

Comment: @BradDalton this isn't a css issue as you might think. And bundled theme related questions **are** on topic

Comment: I've edited your question so that it makes better sense. I hope this is what you had in mind when you wrote the question. If my edit changed the real question and the scope of it, please feel free to roll back my changes. I've answered your question according to my understanding and edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before I answer this question, I would believe that you have already created a [**child theme**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes). **Reason:** You should **never** make any changes to a theme/plugin that you are not the author of. This includes core files

With that sorted, the behavior of the navigation menu in purely controlled by js,

```
  77          /*
  78           * Fixed header for large screen.
  79           * If the header becomes more than 48px tall, unfix the header.
  80           *
  81           * The callback on the scroll event is only added if there is a header
  82           * image and we are not on mobile.
  83           */
  84          if ( _window.width() > 781 ) {
  85              var mastheadHeight = $( '#masthead' ).height(),
  86                  toolbarOffset, mastheadOffset;
  87  
  88              if ( mastheadHeight > 48 ) {
  89                  body.removeClass( 'masthead-fixed' );
  90              }
  91  
  92              if ( body.is( '.header-image' ) ) {
  93                  toolbarOffset  = body.is( '.admin-bar' ) ? $( '#wpadminbar' ).height() : 0;
  94                  mastheadOffset = $( '#masthead' ).offset().top - toolbarOffset;
  95  
  96                  _window.on( 'scroll.twentyfourteen', function() {
  97                      if ( _window.scrollTop() > mastheadOffset && mastheadHeight < 49 ) {
  98                          body.addClass( 'masthead-fixed' );
  99                      } else {
 100                          body.removeClass( 'masthead-fixed' );
 101                      }
 102                  } );
 103              }
 104          }
```

which you can find in functions.js in the js folder

To remove this functionality, (all in your child theme) you'll need to dequeue (using [`wp_dequeue_script()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dequeue_script)) the original functions.js, copy functions.js to your child theme and remove the mentioned lines and enqueue (using [`wp_enqueue_script()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script)) the modified js. This will be done inside a custom function that will be hooked to the [`wp_enqueue_scripts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts) hook

In code and in practice

- Create a file called js in your child theme's root folder.
- Copy functions.js and paste it into your js folder in your child theme
- Open functions.js and remove the line I've mentioned above
- Safe the functions.js

Now, open your child theme's functions.php, and add the following code in there. This will dequeue the parent script and enqueue your new modified script

```
function enqueue_child_functions_js() {

    wp_dequeue_script( 'twentyfourteen-script' ); //dequeue the parent script
    wp_enqueue_script( my-child-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/functions.js', array( 'jquery' ), '20140717', true ); //enqueue new modified script

}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_child_functions_js', 999 );
```

Comment: Sorry this is not what I was looking for. I wanted to build a navigation menu similar to the one on the sample page. A menu that becomes sticky after you scroll pass a top full background image. I was able to do it with a twentythirteen instead. And yes I am using a child theme.

Comment: It shouldn't be to tricky though to accomplish this. As said, the complete behavior of the nav menu is controlled by those few lines of js in my answer. I'm not currently at home, so I can't do any testing, but my thought on this would be to assign a body class of some kind and then tweaking the js accordingly

Comment: Thanks for your help. Your code will definitely come handy on one of my project.

Answer (score 1):

In the Twenty Fourteen theme, the `masthead-fixed` class gets added to the `<body>` element.

The following CSS (line 3362) is actuated as a result:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 783px)
.masthead-fixed .site-header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}
```

You can apply the following CSS from your child theme to override this:

```
.masthead-fixed .site-header {
  position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Thanks I figured it out. Now I am looking for a way to have the navigation sitting on the bottom of the screen when the page first load like in http://www.knapsackcreative.com/

Comment: Beautiful! I appreciate the other answer which is useful for other cases, but this one rocks as it shows a beautiful and SIMPLE design in the theme that allows it to be effortlessly overridden.

Answer (score 1):

Working off of Sepster's answer, the 2014 theme I am working with needed this further addition (here's the full solution that worked for me):

```
.masthead-fixed .site-header {
  position: relative;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 783px) {
    .admin-bar.masthead-fixed .site-header {
        top:inherit;
    }
}
```

Comment: Great addition. Thanks for posting additional info on this :-)

Comment: Thanks. I'm afraid I may have some further problems now still though (with featured content padding stuff). That might be easily fixed as well, but we'll see when I can get back to it hopefully soon. One thing is evident though: if it were possible to simply erase that extra css class, that would take away all the problems. One can test this, just erase it live in the browser inspector. So a jquery solution might be another route to add to all 3 of our current solutions...

Answer (score -1):

According to me `position: unset` is the best and the cleanest option,

Explanation:
I have a Genesis theme running in my website. I liked and uploaded its new version which looked white and clean, but I did not like the sticky or fixed header bar feature of the theme since it was slightly increasing the load time of the page.

I decided to turn off the sticky behavior. I right clicked on the page, investigated the class name of the header bar, checked the CSS option and found it to be having the following details:

```
.site-header {
position: fixed;
```

}

I copied the entire section, and put it in my theme customization box with the the following changes:

```
.site-header {
position: unset;
```

}

And the issue was instantly solved and I could achieve the required results.

I selected "unset" because it simply reverts the situation to the standard or the default version of the theme, and removes any modifications involved with the code.

You can see the the debugging screenshot [here](https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-_GKkhoredLM/Wuv29azy2NI/AAAAAAAARmk/qQFmw2H3-igryn5ZliMVDyF_OPmokhN5wCLcBGAs/s1600/position%2Bunset.png)

Comment: Please **[edit] your answer**, and add an explanation: **why** could that solve the problem and how is it applied?